# Visual Studio Code debugger failing on (M1, 2020, macOS Monterey, ARM64) with C application

Tags: c, arm64, macos-monterey

I am trying to debug a C program in Visual Studio Code on a (M1, 2020, macOS Monterey) and keep getting the same error in the debug console.

`"ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument)"`

My launch.json looks like:

````
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"
        }
    ]
}```

Any suggestions?
````

Answer (score 1):

Take it back, solved it!

Had to change the "type" field in VSC's launch.json file to --> "lldb."

````
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"
        }
    ]
}```
````